# Getting rid of duplicate strings in a column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this:

```
item     tags
1        awesome, awesome, great
2        cool, fun
3        boring, boring, average
4        ok, expensive
```

How can I remove the duplicate tags to get:

```
item     tags
1        awesome, great
2        cool, fun
3        boring, average
4        ok, expensive
```

Comment: a pandas dataframe is not the ideal data structure to deal with this. You should parse this data before inputing it in the data frame

Comment: I’ll second what @rafaelc said. When you’ve got say, strings, or lists in your DataFrames, it’s often a bad sign. It leads to confusion, which is even visible here: You say that you want to remove “duplicate strings”, then call them “tags”. You aren’t removing duplicate strings, and they clearly aren’t just ordinary text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, try:

```
df['new_tags'] = df['tags'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x.split(', '))))
```

Output:

```
   item                     tags         new_tags
0     1  awesome, awesome, great   awesome, great
1     2                cool, fun        cool, fun
2     3  boring, boring, average  average, boring
3     4            ok, expensive    expensive, ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Use listcomp, `str.split`, `pd.unique` and `join`

```
df['unique_tags'] = [', '.join(pd.unique(x)) for x in df.tags.str.split(', ')]

Out[145]:
   item                     tags      unique_tags
0     1  awesome, awesome, great   awesome, great
1     2                cool, fun        cool, fun
2     3  boring, boring, average  boring, average
3     4            ok, expensive    ok, expensive
```

Comment: While OP’s question is clearly problematic, this is a nice solution. Would it still work if the list comprehension were replaced with a generator expression?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile: direct assignment through dictionary mechanism as in this case or through pandas `assign` doesn't call `next` on generator, so it doesn't yield elements in the genex. If using genex, we still need to wrap it inside list constructor to make genex yield out elements.